# Testing window.name in Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I'm working on a simple React app that has opens a new tab with window.open() for a read-only 'presenter' view. I'm writing a test for the conditional rendering in Jest but can't seem to get window.name to change correctly. Specifically, I'm testing the line in which handleStart() is called.

Here's the code that is being tested:

```js
  componentDidUpdate() {
    localStorage.setItem('timeRemaining', this.state.timeRemaining);
    if (window.name === 'presenter' && this.state.timeRemaining > 0) {
      this.handleStart();
    }
  }
```

And here is the test as I currently have it:

```js
    it('checks the window and state to call #handleStart if started in parent view', () => {
      const spy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(), 'handleStart');
      global.window.name === 'presenter';
      wrapper.setState({ timeRemaining: 100 });
      wrapper.update();
      expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I'm a fool and was attempting to assign global.window.name wrong. The test should read

```js
    it('checks the window and state to call #handleStart if started in parent view', () => {
      const spy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(), 'handleStart');
      global.window.name = 'presenter';
      wrapper.setState({ timeRemaining: 100 });
      wrapper.update();
      expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

Leaving this question up as it appears to be unique on here and might be helpful to someone. For reference, if you're testing the Window object in Jest you use 'global' as shown here in lieu of 'window'